# Reload Automatico sem ser preciso

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou com uma duvida! Tenho um sistema de votações, que tem uma pagina que mostra os resultados em directo da votação, esta pagina utiliza para mostrar os gráficos o Google Charts e de fundo tem um codigo ajax que corre a cada 1 segundo, que esta sempre a ir ao arquivo .xml buscar os dados das votações, mas sempre que actualiza da uma ligeira piscada no Grafico, e eu cria que so desse essa piscada quando ha actualizações no numero de votações!

Alguém me pode ajudar a resolver este problema?

Codigo js:

```
window.setInterval(ajax, 1000);
function ajax() {
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
  var res = ajax.responseXML;
  var xml = this;
  var votos1 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
  var votos2 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
  var votos3 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
  var votos4 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
  grafico(votos1, votos2, votos3, votos4);
  }
 }
  ajax.open("POST", "votos.xml");
  ajax.send(null);
 }

 function grafico(votos1, votos2, votos3, votos4){
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['', 'Numero de Votos'],
  ['Opção 1', votos1],
  ['Opção 2', votos2],
  ['Opção 3', votos3],
  ['Opção 4', votos4]
]);
var options = {
  chart: {
    title: 'Total Votações',
    subtitle: 'Ajuda: Publico',
  },
  bars: 'vertical'
};
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('grafico'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}  
}
```

Estrutura XML:

```
<geral>
   <opcao1>
      <votos>5</votos>
      <correta>true</correta>
   </opcao1>
   <opcao2>
      <votos>10</votos>
      <correta>false</correta>
   </opcao2>
   <opcao3>
      <votos>1</votos>
      <correta>false</correta>
   </opcao3>
   <opcao4>
      <votos>20</votos>
      <correta>false</correta>
   </opcao4>
</geral>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma variável simples para guardar os **valores concatenados** e no retorno do Ajax verificar se houve alteração. Ex.:

```
var voTos;
function ajax() {...

var votosAjax = votos1.concat(votos2, votos3, votos4);
// ficará: votosAjax = "510120"
```

Assim, sempre que essa string for diferente da variável `voTos`, você chama a função que atualiza o gráfico e também atualiza o valor de `voTos`:

```
if(votosAjax != voTos){
   voTos = votosAjax;
   grafico(votos1, votos2, votos3, votos4);
}
```

> Como dito na outra resposta, é importante também usar `setTimeout()`
>   somente após o retorno do Ajax, e não `setInterval` da forma que foi
>   feito.

O código ficaria assim:

```
var voTos; // para guardar os valores vindos do Ajax
function ajax() {
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
         var res = ajax.responseXML;
         var xml = this;
         var votos1 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
         var votos2 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
         var votos3 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
         var votos4 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[3].firstChild.nodeValue;

         // valores concatenados vindos do Ajax
         var votosAjax = votos1.concat(votos2, votos3, votos4);

         // verifico se é diferente para chamar a função do gráfico
         if(votosAjax != voTos){
            voTos = votosAjax; // se for diferente, atualizo a variável
            grafico(votos1, votos2, votos3, votos4);
         }

         setTimeout(ajax, 1000);
      }
   }
   ajax.open("POST", "votos.xml");
   ajax.send(null);
}

function grafico(votos1, votos2, votos3, votos4){
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['', 'Numero de Votos'],
      ['Opção 1', votos1],
      ['Opção 2', votos2],
      ['Opção 3', votos3],
      ['Opção 4', votos4]
      ]);
      var options = {
         chart: {
            title: 'Total Votações',
            subtitle: 'Ajuda: Publico',
         },
         bars: 'vertical'
      };
      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('grafico'));
      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
   }  
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   ajax(); // chama a função
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro uma sugestão para trabalhar melhor com Ajax que fica em "loop", mude `setInterval` para `setTimeout`, assim não vai conflitar duas requisições ao mesmo tempo, pois o `setInterval` não espera a requisição terminar o que pode calhar de ficar multiplas requisições ao mesmo tempo, com `setTimeout` dentro do `if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){` vai funcionar melhor.

Sobre checar se houve ou não mudanças você vai precisar criar variáveis para manter os valores (como se fosse um "cache") e verificar eles na próxima requisição Ajax, por exemplo:

> Nota: indentei seu código para ficar mais fácil de entender

```
//Esta variavel servirá para manter um "cache" dos resultados
var cacheVotos = {
    'votos1': 0,
    'votos2': 0,
    'votos3': 0,
    'votos4': 0
};

function ajax() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajax.status == 200) {
                var res = ajax.responseXML;
                var xml = this;
                var votos1 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                var votos2 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
                var votos3 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
                var votos4 = res.getElementsByTagName("votos")[3].firstChild.nodeValue;

                //Se qualquer um deles mudar então grafico() é chamado, caso contrário não
                if (
                    cacheVotos.votos1 != votos1 ||
                    cacheVotos.votos2 != votos2 ||
                    cacheVotos.votos3 != votos3 ||
                    cacheVotos.votos4 != votos4
                ) {
                    //Atualiza os valores do "cache"
                    cacheVotos.votos1 = votos1;
                    cacheVotos.votos2 = votos2;
                    cacheVotos.votos3 = votos3;
                    cacheVotos.votos4 = votos4;

                    grafico(votos1, votos2, votos3, votos4);
                }
            }

            //Isto irá chamar novamente o Ajax após a requisição ter sido concluida
            setTimeout(ajax, 1000);
        }
    }
    ajax.open("POST", "votos.xml");
    ajax.send(null);
}

//Inicia a função
ajax();

function grafico(votos1, votos2, votos3, votos4) {
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['bar']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['', 'Numero de Votos'],
            ['Opção 1', votos1],
            ['Opção 2', votos2],
            ['Opção 3', votos3],
            ['Opção 4', votos4]
        ]);
        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Total Votações',
                subtitle: 'Ajuda: Publico',
            },
            bars: 'vertical'
        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('grafico'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    }
}
```